# How to launch RDP Session using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, desktop

I want to launch Remote Desktop using my ASP.net website. I have tried using .RDP file and use Process class to launch it using MSTSC.exe but I am unable to open the session. So please let me know how can I do that ?

Thanks 
Laxmilal

Comment: on what machine do you wish to run MSTSC.exe ? On the ASPNET server machine, or on the machine running the browser?

Comment: On client browser. Is it works on all OS ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [the approach described by JJ Clements](https://web.archive.org/web/20130801110015/http://www.jjclements.co.uk/index.php/2010/02/21/rdp-hyperlink).

Basically it involves updating the registry on the browser machine, to support an `rdp://` url scheme.  Then, when you click on a link like `rdp://foo`, or when you key in `rdp://foo` into the browser address bar, it opens MSTSC.exe on the browser machine.

Comment: I don't want to change the registry setting of client computer. So is there any other way to do it ?